# How to cancel a scheduled call after that activity is closed?

Tags: java, android

I scheduled a call after 3 sec and I want to cancel it if that activity is closed (user moves to another activity).
Here's my java file:

```
public class EmargencyResponseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_emergency_response);


    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(EmargencyResponseActivity.this,
            Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(EmargencyResponseActivity.this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE},1);


    }
    new CountDownTimer(3000, 1000) {
        public void onFinish() {
            Intent startEmergency = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:108"));
            startActivity(startEmergency);
                finish();
            }

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        }
    }.start();}}
```

Comment: please mark as answer as accepted if it solved your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hold a reference to the timer in your activity and cancel it during `onPause`

```
public class EmargencyResponseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

CountDownTimer timer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //...

    }
    timer = new CountDownTimer(3000, 1000) {
        //Implementation
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause(){
    if (timer != null) timer.cancel();
}

}
```